# Robocopy replaces root folder (sometimes?)

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, robocopy

Something really strange is going on, and I cannot figure out why. I am running the following command on command prompt:

```
robocopy D:\User\Pictures D:\Temp /MIR
```

The first time I run it, it does what you would expect, i.e., copy all files and folders from D:\User\Pictures inside D:\Temp. BUT, if for example I delete something inside D:\Temp, then sometimes (?) it rename D:\Temp to D:\Pictures and proceeds mirroring as expected. I should clarify that this seems to only happen for the folder D:\Pictures, which is the Pictures folder of Windows 10 I am using (i.e, the command "robocopy D:\User\Test D:\Temp /MIR" does not seem to give me any problems).

Comment: It is windows renaming the folder I believe. In fact, I don’t think it is renaming the folder. Instead it is showing you “Pictures” even though the underlying folder is not named that. Go to a command prompt and do a `dir`, is the folder really called “pictures?” I could look in to this more but I know Windows recognizes special user folders and changes how they are displayed in explorer. I’ve seen it cause problem when trying to copy pictures/documents from one user to another user, where it literally creates two “Pictures” folders - because one of them isn’t actually named “Pictures.”

Comment: @Appleoddity You are right. It shows as Pictures in Explorer, but it is actually named Temp when I am running "dir". Is there any way to correct this? Maybe make  it not copy some folder attributes?